# Is there a way to load 128 bits from memory directly to registers?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I know global memory loads of 32, 64, and 128 bits exist in CUDA, but most of the examples use wide loads (i.e. LD.E.128) to copy from memory to memory.

I have multiple arrays of structs similar to this one:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint32_t a,
    uint32_t b,
    uint32_t c,
    uint32_t d
} mystruct_t;
```

Each CUDA thread has to load `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Operates with them, and stores the results in another array of type `mystruct_t`.

Loading the four elements of the struct independently gives a poor performance as memory accesses are not coalesced. This could be fixed by using a structure-of-arrays instead of an array-of-structures pattern, but then L2 caching performance is low when arrays are big (as in my case), as there is little memory locality.

Is it possible to load 128 bits from global memory directly to registers to operate with them? I have tried something similar to this:

```
int4 vector_data = *(int4*)(&myarray[threadIdx.x]);
uint32_t a = vector_data.x;
uint32_t b = vector_data.y;
uint32_t c = vector_data.z;
uint32_t d = vector_data.w;
// Do computations with a, b, c, and d
```

But I still get individual 32 bits uncoalesced loads. I don't know if getting 128 bits into registers is even possible, as registers are 32 bits in most GPUs.

Comment: [inform the compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/T-tPKa) that your struct is properly aligned for a 128-bit load.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments, the GPU compiler will only generate vector load and store instructions on types which have guaranteed alignment to the load and store size.

Consider the following rough adaption of the snippets in your question:

```
#include <cinttypes>

struct mystruct
{
    uint32_t a, b, c, d;
};

struct alignas(16) mystructa
{
    uint32_t a, b, c, d;
};

template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel(T* in, uint32_t* out)
{
   T ival = in[threadIdx.x];
   out[threadIdx.x] = (ival.d - ival.c) * (ival.a + ival.b);
}

template __global__ void kernel<mystruct>(mystruct*, uint32_t*);
template __global__ void kernel<mystructa>(mystructa*, uint32_t*);
```

Here we have a simple kernel which is instantiated with either an aligned or unaligned 128 bit type. The compiler (nvcc 11.3.1 in this case) emits the following PTX:

```
.visible .entry _Z6kernelI8mystructEvPT_Pj(
        .param .u64 _Z6kernelI8mystructEvPT_Pj_param_0,
        .param .u64 _Z6kernelI8mystructEvPT_Pj_param_1
)
{

        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z6kernelI8mystructEvPT_Pj_param_0];
        ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z6kernelI8mystructEvPT_Pj_param_1];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd3, %rd2;
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd4, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        mul.wide.u32    %rd5, %r1, 16;
        add.s64         %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;
        ld.global.u32   %r2, [%rd6];
        ld.global.u32   %r3, [%rd6+4];
        ld.global.u32   %r4, [%rd6+8];
        ld.global.u32   %r5, [%rd6+12];
        sub.s32         %r6, %r5, %r4;
        add.s32         %r7, %r3, %r2;
        mul.lo.s32      %r8, %r6, %r7;
        mul.wide.u32    %rd7, %r1, 4;
        add.s64         %rd8, %rd3, %rd7;
        st.global.u32   [%rd8], %r8;
        ret;

}
.visible .entry _Z6kernelI9mystructaEvPT_Pj(
        .param .u64 _Z6kernelI9mystructaEvPT_Pj_param_0,
        .param .u64 _Z6kernelI9mystructaEvPT_Pj_param_1
)
{

        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z6kernelI9mystructaEvPT_Pj_param_0];
        ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z6kernelI9mystructaEvPT_Pj_param_1];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd3, %rd2;
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd4, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        mul.wide.u32    %rd5, %r1, 16;
        add.s64         %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;
        ld.global.v4.u32        {%r2, %r3, %r4, %r5}, [%rd6];
        sub.s32         %r10, %r5, %r4;
        add.s32         %r11, %r2, %r3;
        mul.lo.s32      %r12, %r10, %r11;
        mul.wide.u32    %rd7, %r1, 4;
        add.s64         %rd8, %rd3, %rd7;
        st.global.u32   [%rd8], %r12;
        ret;

}
```

You can see that in the first kernel instance, supplied with a type as in your question, four separate `ld.global.u32` are used to bring the structure into registers, where as in the second, supplied with the aligned type, a single `ld.global.v4.u32` is used instead.